# Integration of Commonsguy Camera lib for android showing blank preview

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to integrate a CamCoder somewhat like instagram, however as a starter i am trying to place Recorder Preview using following code from Commonsguy lib

MainActivity is as below

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class RecorderActivity extends BaseActivity implements CamCoderView.Contract
{
    //private CamCoderView ffc = null;
    //private CamCoderView std = null;
    private CamCoderView camcoder = null;

    private boolean hasTwoCameras = (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1);
    private boolean singleShot = true;

    private ImageButton captureBtn;
    private ImageButton rotateBtn;  
    private ImageButton doneBtn;    

    private int cameraType = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

    private boolean isCapturePressed = false;

    private ArrayList<String> pathNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String randomPathName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_record_layout);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
        layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
        getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        camcoder = CamCoderView.newInstance(false);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, camcoder ).commit();

        randomPathName =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        captureBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.captureBtn);
        doneBtn    = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        rotateBtn  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rotateBtn);

        if (hasTwoCameras)
            rotateBtn.setEnabled(true);

        rotateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if (cameraType == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                {        
                    cameraType = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                    camcoder = CamCoderView.newInstance(true);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                      .replace(R.id.container, camcoder ).commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    cameraType = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
                    camcoder = CamCoderView.newInstance(false);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                      .replace(R.id.container, camcoder ).commit();                 
                }
            }
        });

        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
            }
        });

        captureBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    if(isCapturePressed == false)
                    {
                        isCapturePressed = true;
                        String path = getOutputMediaFile().getAbsolutePath();
                        pathNames.add(path);
                        camcoder.startRecording(path);
                    }
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    isCapturePressed = false;
                    try {
                        camcoder.stopRecording();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (pathNames != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < pathNames.size(); i++)
            {
                File file = new File(pathNames.get(i));
                if(file.exists())
                {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        }
        finish();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private File getOutputMediaFile() 
    {
        File filesDir = getDir("users", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
        if(!filesDir.isDirectory())
        {
            if (!filesDir.mkdirs()) 
            {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        } 

        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(filesDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "vid_" + randomPathName + "_" + String.valueOf(pathNames.size()) +".mp4");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleShotMode() 
    {
        return(singleShot);
    }   

    @Override
    public void setSingleShotMode(boolean mode) 
    {
        singleShot = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public void callUIMethodForStore(Intent intent) {       
    }   
}
```

CameraView is as follow

```
public class CamCoderView extends CameraFragment
{
    private FrameLayout preview;            
    private static final String KEY_USE_FFC = "USE_FFC";

    static CamCoderView newInstance(boolean useFFC)
    {
        CamCoderView f = new CamCoderView();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean(KEY_USE_FFC, useFFC);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) 
    {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setHost(new MyCameraHost(getActivity()));
      }


    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View cameraView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        preview = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        preview.addView(cameraView);

        if(isAutoFocusAvailable())
        {
            autoFocus();
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class MyCameraHost extends SimpleCameraHost
   {
        boolean supportsFaces=false;

        public MyCameraHost(Context _ctxt) {
          super(_ctxt);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useFrontFacingCamera() {
          return(getArguments().getBoolean(KEY_USE_FFC));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useSingleShotMode() {
          return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void saveImage(byte[] image) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void autoFocusAvailable() {
        }

        @Override
        public void autoFocusUnavailable() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraFail(CameraHost.FailureReason reason) {
          super.onCameraFail(reason);

          Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                         "Sorry, but you cannot use the camera now!",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public Parameters adjustPreviewParameters(Parameters parameters)
        {
          return(super.adjustPreviewParameters(parameters));
        }

    }

    Contract getContract() 
    {
        return((Contract)getActivity());
    }

    interface Contract  
    {
        boolean isSingleShotMode();
        void setSingleShotMode(boolean mode);
    }

    public void startRecording(String path)
    {
        try {
            record();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On my HTC SENSE it is working like a Charm,  however my s3 is not working at all.

[image: S3 Image]

[image: HTC SENSE]

Comment: "Where am i wrong" -- I have no way to know. You will need to determine if you are actually using this fragment, and use tools like Hierarchy View to determine if the `CameraView` from the library is actually on-screen. "what kind of settings should be done" -- you will need to ask Instagram that question.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes the view is on, it just is not displaying the preview, fragment is working fine. Settings actually mean, how am i suppose to set Preview of Video to "Square" and initialize the Recorder :)

Comment: Try the demo apps. If they do not work, then something is off with my support of your device, and I would need to know more. There is no support in this library for a square preview, nor can I see a valid use case for it. I do not know what "initialize the Recorder" means, but to start and stop recording, you call `startRecording()` and `stopRecording()` on the fragment. See Step #3b of [the "Basic Usage" instructions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#basic-usage).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes got it sir, i have actually saw ur demos and look at above code, its quite a copy of your code with few of my tweaks, what i have chnaged is, removed teh actionBar and placed buttons on main activity. It works ABSOLUTELY FINE on my HTC, however yesterday i was testing on my s3 and still on S3 it just showing no Camera Preview, hoewver your demo works fine. Please check the images too

Comment: I have no way of helping you further. You are going to need to determine what is different between the demo and your code, and slowly modify one to look like the other, until the problem changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's what i did , but look at the images :) HTC is fine and not S3 !!!

Comment: You state "your demo works fine". Hence, I have already given you working code. It is *your* job to determine where *your* code differs from the working code and what *specific* bit of *your* code is causing your problem. If that specific bit of code represents something that I think should be supported, it's probably a bug in my library, and I will strive to fix it. By "specific", I mean a couple of lines with accompanying notes (e.g., "if I comment out these lines, it works" or "if I pass `false` instead of `true`, it works").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is fixed, it seems tht

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <!-- <item name="android:background">@drawable/main_bg</item> -->
    <!-- <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/main_bg</item> -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

Settings Theme on Application was causing this problem, i have removed this and now its working ok !! strange